# Monotone approximation of continuous function by Lipschitz function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space, and $f\in C_b(X,\mathbb{R})$. How can I construct a sequence $\varphi_k,\,k\geq 1$ of bounded Lipschitz functions with $\varphi_k\downarrow f$ pointwise? Thanks

Comment: How about $\varphi_k(x) = \sup\{f(y) - k \|x - y\| : y \in X\}$?

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference for this approach?

Comment: Not really; it is a simple exercise, though.

Comment: Looks like this works for any metric space $X$. Nice!